# Knife tool just not working on simple object

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

I'm trying to slice my 'house' so I can create a ridge, but the knife tool doesn't seem to work on this object at all. Despite snapping to the verticies correctly, as soon as I press enter, it just disappears instead of confirming the new edge as normal.

What am I doing wrong?   My Blend is here: [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why, but if you uncheck the 'Occlude Geometry' option it works correctly.

[image]

It may be because the top face of your model is not an ngon (has 5 vertices).

Comment: Thanks!  It is better to stick with quads?  I probably oversimplified my model using Dissolve Faces.

Comment: Yes definitely. On a shape that simple there's no point in disolving faces anyway. You've ended up with edges with a single vertex in the middle in this case.

Comment: I don't actually have the Occlude Geometry option for some reason (2.91)

Comment: Just tried it again and that option only appears if you access the knife tool by clicking on the option in the toolbar or use Shift-Space > k. It doesn't appear if you simply use the 'k' key though!